# Trying to convert this Assembly code to C code

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

```
# x at %ebp+8, n at %ebp+12
movl 8(%ebp), %esi
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
movl $-1, %edi
movl $1, %edx
.L2:
movl %edx, %eax
andl %esi, %eax
xorl %eax, %edi
movl %ebx, %ecx
sall %cl, %edx
testl %edx, %edx
jne .L2
movl %edi, %eax
```

I converted the above code to the below code, but i am not completely sure if it is correct.

```
    int loop(int x, int n){

    int result = -1;

    for (mask = 1; mask >= result; mask = x&1) {

    result ^= n;

    }
return result;
}
```

x and n are two integers stored in %ebp memory and are moved to registry %esi and %ebx. Result and Mask have a value of -1 and 1 and that is from the first part of the code 
I think after `.L2:` the loop starts and that is where i get confused.
At the end result is returned `movl %edi, %eax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely wrong. You should have done some test by yourself before posting quesetions.

First of all, `mask` in your code is not declared in your function.

Then, after declareing `mask` as `int`, the function `loop` will fall into an infinite loop when `result` won't become positive via `result ^= n;`. On the other hand, the assembly code won't fall into an infinite loop unless `n` is multiple of 32 (including zero).

To convert the code to assembly:

1. I did direct conversion from assembly to C.

Note that I used unsigned type `uint32_t` because

- Use unsigned type because left shift operation to signed integer will cause *undefined behavior* when overflow occures or the value to be shifted is negative.
- Use `uint32_t` because size of `unsigned int` is dependent to environments and it may be less than 32-bit long while registers used here (except for `%cl`) are 32-bit long.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators:

> 4 The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Also note that `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h` has to be included to use `uint32_t`.

The width to shift is masked to 5-bit long in x86 CPUs that is 80286 or later.

```
uint32_t loop(uint32_t x, uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t esi = x;              /* movl 8(%ebp), %esi         */
    uint32_t ebx = n;              /* movl 12(%ebp), %ebx        */
    uint32_t edi = -1;             /* movl $-1, %edi             */
    uint32_t edx = 1;              /* movl $1, %edx              */
    uint32_t eax, ecx;
    do {                           /* .L2:                       */
        eax = edx;                 /* movl %edx, %eax            */
        eax &= esi;                /* andl %esi, %eax            */
        edi ^= eax;                /* xorl %eax, %edi            */
        ecx = ebx;                 /* movl %ebx, %ecx            */
        edx <<= (ecx & 0xff) & 31; /* sall %cl, %edx             */
    } while (edx != 0);            /* testl %edx, %edx ; jne .L2 */
    eax = edi;                     /* movl %edi, %eax            */
    return eax;
}
```

2. I introduced variable names to make their roles clear.

```
uint32_t loop(uint32_t x, uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t result = -1;
    uint32_t mask = 1;
    uint32_t eax, ecx;
    do {
        eax = mask;
        eax &= x;
        result ^= eax;
        ecx = n;
        mask <<= (ecx & 0xff) & 31;
    } while (mask != 0);
    return result;
}
```

3. I merged some expressions.

```
uint32_t loop(uint32_t x, uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t result = -1;
    uint32_t mask = 1;
    do {
        result ^= mask & x;
        mask <<= n & 31;
    } while (mask != 0);
    return result;
}
```

4. I changed `do` loop to `for` loop because your attempt uses it.

```
uint32_t loop(uint32_t x, uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t result = -1;
    uint32_t mask;
    for (mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= n & 31) {
        result ^= mask & x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Full code for testing and [demo](https://ideone.com/DDwbXB):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>

__asm__ (
/* support both environments that does and doesn't add underscore before function name */
"loop_asm:\n"
"_loop_asm:\n"
"push %ebp\n"
"mov %esp, %ebp\n"
"push %esi\n"
"push %edi\n"
"push %ebx\n"

"# x at %ebp+8, n at %ebp+12\n"
"movl 8(%ebp), %esi\n"
"movl 12(%ebp), %ebx\n"
"movl $-1, %edi\n"
"movl $1, %edx\n"
".L2_test:\n" /* rename .L2 to .L2_test to avoid collision */
"movl %edx, %eax\n"
"andl %esi, %eax\n"
"xorl %eax, %edi\n"
"movl %ebx, %ecx\n"
"sall %cl, %edx\n"
"testl %edx, %edx\n"
"jne .L2_test\n"
"movl %edi, %eax\n"

"pop %ebx\n"
"pop %edi\n"
"pop %esi\n"
"leave\n"
"ret\n"
);

uint32_t loop_asm(uint32_t, uint32_t);

uint32_t loop_convert(uint32_t x, uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t result = -1;
    uint32_t mask;
    for (mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= n & 31) {
        result ^= mask & x;
    }
    return result;
}

int mask;
    int loop(int x, int n){

    int result = -1;

    for (mask = 1; mask >= result; mask = x&1) {

    result ^= n;

    }
return result;
}

int main(void) {
    int x, n;
    uint32_t raw, test, conv;
    int miss_count = 0;
    /* search for mismatch in some range */
    for (n = 1; n < 32; n++) {
        uint32_t x_test;
        for (x_test = 0; x_test < UINT32_C(100000); x_test++) {
            if (loop_asm(x, n) != loop_convert(x, n)) {
                printf("mismatch at x=%"PRIu32", n=%d\n", x_test, n);
                if (miss_count < INT_MAX) miss_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d mismatch(es) found.\n", miss_count);
    /* print some examples */
    x = 100;
    n = 5;
    raw = loop_asm(x, n);
    conv = loop_convert(x, n);
    printf("loop_asm(%d, %d) = %"PRIu32"\n", x, n, raw);
    printf("loop_convert(%d, %d) = %"PRIu32"\n", x, n, conv);
    fflush(stdout);
    test = loop(x, n);
    printf("loop(%d, %d) = %"PRIu32"\n", x, n, test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, Thank you! this helped a lot